# Filtering data that could have more than one category

Tags: postgresql

I have a table like the following:

```
Annotation (
    document,
    term,
    category
)
```

Where `document` and `term` are some ID, while `category` is an integer.

The couple `document` - `term` is not unique, i.e. I could have the same couple with a different category.

```
document_id_1, term_id_1, category_1
document_id_1, term_id_1, category_2
document_id_1, term_id_1, category_3
```

I would like to design a query such that it return only the couple `document`-`term` for whom there exists a only a row with `category = 1`.

E.g. in the previous example the couple `document_id_1` - `term_id_1` is not returned becouse there exist also other two rows, with different values of `category`.

Can you give me some hints on how to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, one way to achieve this is getting those rows where `category = 1`, then check for the non-existence of non-category1 rows:

```
SELECT document, term
FROM Annotation ann
WHERE 
    category = 1
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM Annotation a
        WHERE 
            a.document = ann.document
            AND a.term = ann.term
            AND category <> 1
    )
;
```

(Thanks to DavideChicco.it for showing that this was overly complicated).

Comment: @dezso Is the first "EXISTS ( SELECT .." query mandatory? I tried this:  `SELECT document, term
FROM Annotation ann
WHERE category = 1
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM Annotation a
        WHERE 
            a.document = ann.document
            AND a.term = ann.term
            AND category <> 1
    )`. Is this correct the same?

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to use something similar to this:

```
select a1.document, a1.term, a1.category
from annotation a1
where category = 1
  and exists (select document, term
              from annotation a2
              where a1.document = a2.document
                and a1.term = a2.term
              group by document, term
              having count(distinct category) = 1)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/17657/6).

This will filter for the rows where the `category =1` but then checks to make sure that the `document` and `term` only has one distinct row in the table.

Answer (score 7):

If this is PostgreSQL 8.4+, you could also try the following:

```
WITH counted AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY document, term) AS category_count
  FROM Annotation
)
SELECT
  document,
  term,
  category
FROM counted
WHERE category = 1
  AND category_count = 1
;
```

The `counted` Common Table Expression returns rows supplied with row counts per every partition of `(document, term)`. The main query only needs to filter on the condition that a row belongs to a specific category and that the corresponding row count is 1.

Note also that if your design allows duplicate entries of `(document, term, category)`, you'll need to replace `COUNT(*)` with `COUNT(DISTINCT category)`. (That may accordingly result in more than one row per `(document, term)` in the output.)